# Permission error trying to create a new COM+ Application in Win7

Tags: windows-7

I am logged in as domain user who is part of the local Administrators group.

However when I try to register a new COM+ application in windows 7 ultimate via the Component Services MMC, I get a "You do not have permission to perform the requested operation" error.

Any idea how that can be fixed?

TIA

Comment: I get the same error even if I login as with the Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the installer as Administrator. Just being logged in as admin doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I am trying to manually add the COM+ application via the Component Services MMC which was opened via Run As Administrator.

Comment: ok do you have an event id tied to this event?  Also you said that your in a domain does the domain have gpo's controlling com+ settings.

Comment: I dont see an event in the log. Also, I get the same error when I login as another Admin non-domain user.